# Is there a way to assign 'group id' by start and end of consecutive rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a group for sequential rows by the user. I've tried a few different options. The closest I've gotten is by rounding the datetime to the nearest 30 mins and using dense rank as follows;

DENSE_RANK() over (order by user_id, dateTimeRoundNear) as grouping
while this gets me close I believe there has to be a more accurate way to do it. The data is below, the last column, desired_group is the output I'm looking for. Any help is much appreciated!

Ideally I'd like to create group ids by user_id and event_order so every sequential group by user_id would get an id

user_id | event_order | desired_group

xxxx1           1            1

xxxx1           2            1

xxxx1           3            1

xxxx1           1            2

xxxx1           2            2

xxxx1           2            3

**Update:** please use the below script to create the dataset. Ideally we would be able to programmatically mimic the desired_group column.

```
create table #test
(ID integer,
user_id integer,
SendDate datetime,
event_type varchar(255),
event_order integer,
dateTimeRoundNear datetime,
grouping integer,
desired_group integer
);

insert into #test
(ID, user_id, SendDate, event_type, event_order, dateTimeRoundNear, grouping, desired_group)
values
(13329832,  125440, '20190927 01:07:18 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:00:00 AM', 1,  1),
(13329832,  125440, '20190927 01:07:18 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:00:00 AM', 1,  1),
(13330033,  125440, '20190927 01:08:22 AM', 'pwreset', 3,   '20190927 01:00:00 AM', 1, 1),
(13331789,  12992,  '20190927 01:15:10 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 13, 2),
(13331790,  12992,  '20190927 01:15:10 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 13, 2),
(13332009,  12992,  '20190927 01:16:20 AM', 'pwreset',  3,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 13, 2),
(13332719,  128016, '20190927 01:20:37 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  3),
(13332720,  128016, '20190927 01:20:37 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  3),
(13332857,  128016, '20190927 01:21:23 AM', 'pwreset',  3,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  3),
(13334671,  128016, '20190927 01:31:24 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  4),
(13334672,  128016, '20190927 01:31:24 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  4),
(13334713,  128016, '20190927 01:31:34 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  5),
(13334714,  128016, '20190927 01:31:34 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  5),
(13334898,  149296, '20190927 01:32:34 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 25, 6),
(13334899,  149296, '20190927 01:32:34 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 25, 6),
(13334978,  128016, '20190927 01:32:42 AM', 'pwsent',   1,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  7),
(13334980,  128016, '20190927 01:32:42 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 01:30:00 AM', 9,  7),
(13348681,  201264, '20190927 03:59:09 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 04:00:00 AM', 68, 8),
(13376580,  317408, '20190927 09:54:03 AM', 'pwchange', 2,  '20190927 10:00:00 AM', 108,9);
select 
*
from #test;
```

[screenshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQyIG.png)

Comment: Proper columns would be great!

Comment: I hear you man. I'm new and trying to figure it out!

Comment: Please explain the rules that you want to implement *explicitly*.  Don't make people try to guess from the data.

Comment: Try row_number() instead of dense rank. Row_number will only partition on what you specify, dense_rank() will partition based on uniqueness.

Comment: So the rules would be that when an event_order <= the previous event_order then assign a new group_id. I think that makes sense

Comment: sorry about the screenshot, I can't figure out how to post the example in a way that's reasonably formatted.

Comment: Hi Micah. I took [this](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) link from another stack overflow post.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

Your final column is enumerating rows with "pwchange", as far as I can tell.

This would be:

```
select t.*,
       (case when event_type = 'pwchange'
             then row_number() over (partition by event_type order by senddate)
        end) as final_group
from t;
```

Comment: thanks for the response, the column event_order is an ordering of how the events should happen in the system. The event type should not be considered. it's really anytime numeration is broken then start a new group_id. so for example, user_id is xxxxxx he has 1, 2, 3 / 2,3 / 2,/ 1. each of the items separated by '/' should be a group.